# How does optind and argv behave in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, argv, getopt

I've been reading Head First C and I'm currently stuck at understanding `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and the `optind` variable of `getopt()`. I'm troubled by the same program as the one in [How does "optind" get assigned in C?](https://www.stackoverflow.com/), unfortunately I still can't get my head over what's going on even after reading that question and man pages. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *delivery = "";
    int thick = 0;
    int count = 0;
    char ch;

    printf("optind before loop is %i\n", optind);

    while ( (ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != EOF)
    {
        printf("optind before switch is %i\n", optind);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'd':
                delivery = optarg;
                printf("argc in case d is %i\n", argc);
                printf("argv in case d is %c\n", *argv);
                printf("optind in case d is %i\n", optind);
                break;
            case 't':
                thick = 1;
                printf("argc in case t is %i\n", argc);
                printf("argv in case t is %c\n", *argv);
                printf("optind in case t is %i\n", optind);
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option: '%s'\n", optarg);
                return 1;
        }
        printf("after switch optind is %i\n", optind);
        printf("----------------\n");
    }

    printf("after loop argc is %i\n", argc);
    printf("after loop argv is %c\n", *argv);
    printf("after loop optind is %i\n", optind);
    printf("----------------\n");

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    printf("final argc is %i\n", argc);
    printf("final argv is %c\n", *argv);
    printf("final optind is %i\n", optind);

    if (thick) puts("Thick crust.");
    if (delivery[0]) printf("To be delivered %s.\n", delivery);

    puts("Ingredients:");

    for (count = 0 ; count < argc; count++)
    {
        puts(argv[count]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I ran the program with `./order_pizza bacon -d now -t shrimp` and got the following output:

```
optind before loop is 1
optind before switch is 4
argc in case d is 6
argv in case d is O
optind in case d is 4
after switch optind is 4
----------------
argc in case t is 6
argv in case t is O
optind in case t is 5
after switch optind is 5
----------------
after loop argc is 6
after loop argv is O
after loop optind is 4
----------------
final argc is 2
final argv is ]
final optind is 4
Thick crust.
To be delivered now.
Ingredients:
bacon
pineapple
```

The code works fine, but I don't fully understand its internals. Here are my issues:

1. `char *argv[]` in `main` is an array of pointers, in which each pointer points to the first character of the respective argument string, and `argv` is actually `argv[0]` right? And argv[0] is the address of the first character of `./order_pizza`, which is `.`. But why does my output say `argv` was first `O` then `]` (characters that don't even exist in my input)?
2. According to the [getopt() man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt), "`getopt()` permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end". Does this mean that after scanning, `argv` becomes `{"./order_pizza","-d","now","-t","bacon","shrimp"}`? Would the order of options and arguments be kept the same (like, could the permutated array possibly be turned into `{"./order_pizza","-t","now","-d","shrimp","bacon"}` instead)?
3. After the `while` loop, `optind` is 4, so `argv += optind` should be equivalent to `argv[0] = argv[0] + 4;`, which looks like adding 4 to the address of `.` (the first character `./order_pizza`) to me. Given the array has now been permutated into `{"./order_pizza","-d","now","-t","bacon","shrimp"}`, shouldn't we be trying to do `argv[0] = argv[4];` or `argv = arg[optind]` instead?
4. The argument vector starts with the element `./order_pizza`. The man page says "If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1. Then optind is the index in argv of the first argv-element that is not an option. ". Since the vector is `{"./order_pizza","-d","now","-t","bacon","shrimp"}` after the processing, why would `optind` be 4 (the index of `bacon`) instead of 0 (the index of `./order_pizza`). I know the former is what we want, but does `./order_pizza` not count as an argv-element?
5. *Head First C* states that "optind stores the number of strings read from the command line to get past the options", which seems to conflict with the [getopt() man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt), which states `optind` is an index number. Is this an oversight of the book's authors, or did I miss something and the authors are indeed correct?

The answers to the old question regarding this program helped me a lot, yet I still have the problems listed above. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: The C standard specifies that `EOF` is negative, not necessarily -1, despite of what most implementations define it as. So test against -1, not `EOF`.

Comment: Those `printfs()` invoke undefined behaviour. `%c` expects a `char`, not a `char *`.

Comment: OT, but there are some other issues with your code .Given `char ch;` the comparison `(ch = getopt(argc, argv, "d:t")) != EOF` is wrong.  First, `getopt()` returns `int`, not `char`, and `EOF` is not representable as a `char` value.  (Assuming `sizeof(char)<sizeof(int)`, anyway).  Also, [`getopt()` returns `-1`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getopt.html), not `EOF`.

Comment: (cont) [`EOF` is *not* `-1`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3): "`EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value"  Using the wrong types and values is a great way to introduce subtle bugs that can be very hard to find the cause of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. `char *argv[]` in main is an array of pointers,

It's a *pointer* to the first `char *` in such an array, actually.  It is a quirk of C that array syntax can be used in a function parameter list to indicate a pointer.  It would be equivalent -- in a function parameter list only -- to declare `argv` as `char **argv`.  And some people do.

> in which each pointer points to the first character of the respective argument
> string,

Yes.

> and `argv` is actually `argv[0]` right?

**No.  `argv[0]` has one less level of indirection than does `argv`.  The two cannot refer to the same object.**  For any valid pointer `p`, `p[0]` is equivalent to `*p`.  That includes `argv`: **`argv[0]` is equivalent to `*argv`, not to `argv` itself.**

> And `argv[0]` is the address
> of the first character of `./order_pizza`, which is `.`.

Yes, when you launch the program via the command shown.

> But why does my
> output say `argv` was first `O` then `]` (characters that don't even exist
> in my input)?

It doesn't say that.  ***Your program produces undefined behavior when it attempts to print `*argv`, a `char *`  (see above), via `printf` conversion specifier `%c`, which is for values of type `char`.***

A good C compiler would warn you about that mismatch.  If yours isn't warning then either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

---

> 2. According to the getopt() man page, "`getopt()` permutes the contents of argv as it scans, so that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end".

Note well that this is a characteristic of the default behavior of the GNU implementation of `getopt()`, which differs in this regard from the the behavior specified by POSIX (which is to just stop option processing when the first non-option argument is found).

> Does this mean that after scanning, `argv` becomes `{"./order_pizza","-d","now","-t","bacon","shrimp"}`?

In your example command, `"./order_pizza"` is the command name, "`-d`" and `"now"` are an option and its option-argument, and `"-t"` is another option (that does not accept an argument).  The remaining elements of `argv`, `"bacon"` and `"shrimp"`, are the non-option arguments, and it is these that are permuted to the end.

> Would the order of options and arguments be kept the same (like, could the permutated array possibly be turned into `{"./order_pizza","-t","now","-d","shrimp","bacon"}` instead)?

The docs don't specify, but I expect the relative order of the non-option arguments to be retained.  That is, I expect the first ordering you suggest, not the alternative order you propose.  If `getopt()` reordered non-option arguments then it would be unsuitable for a variety of common command idioms.  For example, it would be very bad if `getopt()` processing converted `mv a b -f` to `mv -f b a`.  Such an argument is not the same thing as documentation, though.

---

> 3. After the while loop, `optind` is 4, so `argv += optind` should be equivalent to `argv[0] = argv[0] + 4;`,

Absolutely not.  `argv` is not the same thing as `argv[0]` (ever).  `argv += optind` is equivalent to `argv = &argv[optind]`.  That is, it updates `argv` to point to (the pointer to) the first non-option argument.

---

> 4. The argument vector starts with the element `./order_pizza`. The man page says "If there are no more option characters, getopt() returns -1. Then optind is the index in argv of the first argv-element that is not an option. ". Since the vector is `{"./order_pizza","-d","now","-t","bacon","shrimp"}` after the processing, why would `optind` be 4 (the index of `bacon`) instead of 0 (the index of `./order_pizza`).

The text is a little misleading there.  Instead of "the first argv-element that is not an option", it would be more accurate to say "the first non-option argument, or the trailing null pointer if there are no non-option arguments".  This is also consistent with the rest of the description of how `getopt()` maintains the value of `optind`.  And it makes sense to do this, though that's not safe to use as a primary criterion.

> I know the former is what we want, but does `./order_pizza` not count as an argv-element?

Yes, `./order_pizza` is an argv element, but it is not what the manual means here.

---

> 5. *Head First C* states that "optind stores the number of strings read from the command line to get past the options", which seems to
>    conflict with the getopt() man page, which states `optind` is an index
>    number. Is this an oversight of the book's authors, or did I miss
>    something and the authors are indeed correct?

The book and the manual page do not conflict, though the book is a little looser when applied to the GNU version of `getopt()`.  Suppose the command were issued as

```
./order_pizza -d now -t bacon shrimp
```

After `getopt()` has processed all the options, as determined by it returning -1, the value of `optind` will be 4.  This is the index of the first non-option argument, `"bacon"`, in `argv`.  It is also the number of *preceding* strings in `argv`.  This is what the book means.

The book is in fact exactly right for POSIX-conforming `getopt()`, but not entirely correct for the default behavior of GNU's version of `getopt()`.  This is because GNU `getopt()` has the behavior we already discussed of looking through the whole argument list for options instead of stopping at the first non-option argument.  Nevertheless, the idea it is trying to convey is the same: after `getopt()` has processed all the options, `optind` tells you where in `argv` the non-option arguments start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my head much clearer! Now I know I forgot that all variables have adreesses of their own, so in reality, `*argv` == `argv[0]` and `argv` == `&argv[0]`,  which means the value of `argv` is the address of `argv[0]`, but not the element `argv[0]` itself, and the value of `argv[0]` is the address of the first character of the first string. Thank you again!